# How to use BeyondCompare from command line, but Visual Studio diff within VS?

Tags: git, visual-studio, diff, beyondcompare

When working in Visual Studio, when I diff a file from the Git Changes pane it has always shown the diff within Visual Studio using the VS integrated diff tool.

When working from the command line, I had Beyond Compare set to be the default diff tool by following [their instructions](https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#gitwindows).

Recently Visual Studio has upgraded to version 16.11.5

Now my workflow is broken. It seems that when I use `git difftool` from the commandline, nothing happens. If I refollow the instructions above, then diffing from the commandline starts working again. But this breaks Visual Studio, if I then click a file to diff it in Visual Studio this starts BeyondCompare instead of using the Visual Studio integrated difftool. If I put that back in the Visual Studio options to use the integrated difftool, then that again breaks the command line diff.

How can I configure this as required:

- Diff commands within Visual Studio use the integrated Visual Studio diff tool.
- Diff commands from the command line use Beyond Compare.

Comment: If you scroll to the end of that link you will find the instructions specific for Visual Studio

Comment: @Steve Thanks, but I do NOT want to use BeyondCompare from within Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry, I have posted without really understanding your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `git bash`, run `git config --list` to view your current command line settings. These are mine that show Beyond Compare for both `diff` and `merge` tools.

```
diff.tool=bc
difftool.bc.path=c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe
merge.tool=bc
mergetool.bc.path=c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe
```

In VSCode, I can see changes via the internal `diff` tool and on the source control menu, I can right-click a changed file and opt to see the changes via the CLI configured `difftool` (Beyond Compare).

[image: VSCode Source Control]

This is what you want to get back to with Visual Studio (not VSC), correct?

Try unsetting all of these settings and see how VS reacts. Does it go back to the default internal diff or not?

```
git config --global --unset diff.tool
git config --global --unset merge.tool
```

Otherwise, you might just need to [reset your settings in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-settings?view=vs-2019#visual-studio-settings).

Comment: I tried that and it worked thanks! I now get the VS diff tool when doing a diff from inside VS. And I get BeyondCompare when I do a diff from the command line.

I don't understand how this works. I fully expected your suggestion would fix VS, but would stop BeyondCompare working when I run "git difftool" on the command line. But it does appear to work for now.